# Is wildcard in Robots.txt in middle of string recognized?

Tags: robots.txt

I need some string for robots.txt like:

```
disallow: 

/article/*/
```

but I don't know if this is a proper way to do this or not?!

I need, for example, the following URLs to be followed:

- `/article/hello`
- `/article/123`

But the following should be blocked:

- `/article/hello/add`
- `/article/123/768&goshopping`

Comment: [Cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25612015/1591669).

Answer (score 3):

```
Disallow: /article/*/
```

Yes, this should be OK and work as required in the main search engines. Note that this must appear on one line, not split as in your example.

The *wildcard* `*` is an extension to the original robots.txt standard and "[designates 0 or more instances of any valid character](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt)" (according to Google).